# Can I use a can of 'make your own' marmalade beyond the 'best before' date?

Tags: marmalade

I have a can of ‘make your own marmalade’. It’s three years after its 'best before' date. Will it be safe to use?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the product? Perhaps share a photo?

Comment: Where does the "best before" date come from in a marmelade you made yourself?

Comment: @njzk2 - Not a marmalade they have made, but a can of Seville oranges already peeled and cut up so that you only have to cook them.

Comment: @KateBunting why would anyone do that? Did peeling and cutting oranges became suddenly a mildly complex task?

Comment: Not 'suddenly' - canned Seville oranges have been on sale in the UK for many years. Fresh ones are only available [for a short time](https://www.cobbsfarmshops.co.uk/blog/tis-the-season-for-home-made-marmalade#:~:text=It%27s%20famous%20for%20flamenco%20dancing,December%20through%20to%20mid%2DFebruary.) and I suppose it is quite troublesome to prepare enough of them for a batch of marmalade.

Answer (score 6):

Canned foods should be stable for many years, and I've certainly used [Ma Made](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/254850756) brand well after its date. It is after all a *best before* (quality) and not a *use by* (safety) date.

However I've also rejected a tin only about a year out of date. It was slightly bulging and may have leaked (if not something sticky had got on the bottom edge somehow). When I opened it, to get rid of the contents, there was obviously excess pressure. It smelt slightly off, I think, but I didn't have a known good tin for comparison and the smell of Seville oranges is a bit unusual anyway. I've had similar with tinned tomatoes well past their date - my guess is that if there's a pinhole in the coating on the inside, acidic foods react with the tin.

So exercise a little caution, including when opening if in doubt.

Comment: I've had "neglected too long" canned mandarin oranges eat through the can. +1